# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientToken')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

Though the `clientToken` has been defined and assigned a value, it is showing undefined properties, why?

The API call has been working fine, the URL is fine, but still it showing this error, can anyone help me with this.

Below is the error detial.

```
 if (info && info.error) {
  26 |     setInfo({ ...info, error: info.error });
  27 |   } else {
> 28 |     const clientToken = info.clientToken;
     | ^  29 |     setInfo({ clientToken });
  30 |   }
  31 | });
```

getToken object is below.

```
  const getToken = (userId, token) => {
    getmeToken(userId, token).then(info => {
      // console.log("INFORMATION", info);
      if (info && info.error) {
        setInfo({ ...info, error: info.error });
      } else {
        const clientToken = info.clientToken;
        setInfo({ clientToken });
      }
    });
  };
```

getmeToken component below.

```
export const getmeToken = (userId, token) => {
    return fetch(` ${API}/payment/gettoken/${userId}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `info` don't have property `clientToken`, because it return  `undefined`. Log `info` and check it structure

Comment: const Paymentb = ({ products, setReload = f => f, reload = undefined }) => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    loading: false,
    success: false,
    clientToken: null,
    error: "",
    instance: {}
  });

Comment: function `getmeToken` return `response.json();` this is your `info` and not the state `[info, setInfo]`

Comment: `getmeToken(userId, token).then(info => {` in this block `info` is not a state

Comment: @VitaliyRayets Yes

Answer (score 0):

In your `else` condition you're never checking if `info` has been defined and it most likely isn't. The issue probably doesn't come from `clientToken` itself but from `info` being `undefined` or `null`.

You can try to do something like this:

```
if (info) {
  if (info.error) {
    setInfo({ ...info, error: info.error });
  } else {
    const clientToken = info.clientToken;
    setInfo({ clientToken });
  }
}
```

Comment: const Paymentb = ({ products, setReload = f => f, reload = undefined }) => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    loading: false,
    success: false,
    clientToken: null,
    error: "",
    instance: {}
  });

Comment: ok then rename the variable `info` from your callback to something like `infoResult` `getmeToken(userId, token).then(infoResult => ... )`, it probably collides with your state `info` variable.

Comment: Didn't make a difference